# What is this ```typedef``` declaration?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, function-pointers, typedef, designated-initializer

I was researching about state machines using C, and I ran into this code from [this site](https://aticleworld.com/state-machine-using-c/).
There is some `typedef` declaration that I had never seen before:

```c
    typedef eSystemState (*const afEventHandler[last_State][last_Event])(void);
```

and it is used here:

```c
    // Table to define valid states and event of finite state machine
    static afEventHandler StateMachine =
    {
        [Idle_State] ={[Card_Insert_Event]= InsertCardHandler },
        [Card_Inserted_State] ={[Pin_Enter_Event] = EnterPinHandler },
        [Pin_Eentered_State] ={[Option_Selection_Event] = OptionSelectionHandler},
        [Option_Selected_State] ={[Amount_Enter_Event] = EnterAmountHandler},
        [Amount_Entered_State] ={[Amount_Dispatch_Event] = AmountDispatchHandler},
    };
```

Can somebody please explain what this is? Here is the full code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

//Different state of ATM machine
typedef enum
{
    Idle_State,
    Card_Inserted_State,
    Pin_Eentered_State,
    Option_Selected_State,
    Amount_Entered_State,
    last_State
} eSystemState;

//Different type events
typedef enum
{
    Card_Insert_Event,
    Pin_Enter_Event,
    Option_Selection_Event,
    Amount_Enter_Event,
    Amount_Dispatch_Event,
    last_Event
} eSystemEvent;

//typedef of 2d array
typedef eSystemState (*const afEventHandler[last_State][last_Event])(void);

//typedef of function pointer
typedef eSystemState (*pfEventHandler)(void);

//function call to dispatch the amount and return the ideal state
eSystemState AmountDispatchHandler(void)
{
    return Idle_State;
}

//function call to Enter amount and return amount enetered state
eSystemState EnterAmountHandler(void)
{
    return Amount_Entered_State;
}

//function call to option select and return the option selected state
eSystemState OptionSelectionHandler(void)
{
    return Option_Selected_State;
}

//function call to enter the pin and return pin entered state
eSystemState EnterPinHandler(void)
{
    return Pin_Eentered_State;
}

//function call to processing track data and return card inserted state
eSystemState InsertCardHandler(void)
{
    return Card_Inserted_State;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    eSystemState eNextState = Idle_State;
    eSystemEvent eNewEvent;

// Table to define valid states and event of finite state machine
    static afEventHandler StateMachine =
    {
        [Idle_State] ={[Card_Insert_Event]= InsertCardHandler },
        [Card_Inserted_State] ={[Pin_Enter_Event] = EnterPinHandler },
        [Pin_Eentered_State] ={[Option_Selection_Event] = OptionSelectionHandler},
        [Option_Selected_State] ={[Amount_Enter_Event] = EnterAmountHandler},
        [Amount_Entered_State] ={[Amount_Dispatch_Event] = AmountDispatchHandler},
    };

    while(1)
    {
        // assume api to read the next event
        eSystemEvent eNewEvent = ReadEvent();
        //Check NULL pointer and array boundary
        if( ( eNextState < last_State) && (eNewEvent < last_Event) && StateMachine[eNextState][eNewEvent]!= NULL)
        {
            // function call as per the state and event and return the next state of the finite state machine
            eNextState = (*StateMachine[eNextState][eNewEvent])();
        }
        else
        {
            //Invalid
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the typedef

```
typedef eSystemState (*const afEventHandler[last_State][last_Event])(void);
```

step by step.

This

```
afEventHandler[last_State][last_Event]
```

declares a two dimensional array. Taking into account that the enumerators `last_State` and `lastEvent` are equal to `5` then the above record is equivalent to

```
afEventHandler[5][5]
```

This

```
*const afEventHandler[last_State][last_Event]
```

declares a two-dimensional array of constant pointers (the pointers themselves are constant).

And at last this

```
typedef eSystemState (*const afEventHandler[last_State][last_Event])(void);
```

declares a two-dimensional array of constant pointers to functions of the type `eSystemState ( void )`. That is the function has the return type `eSystemState`  and the parameter list `void`.

Thus the name `afEventHandler` is a synonym for the type of a two-dimensional array of constant pointers to functions of the type `eSystemState ( void )`

As for this declaration

```
// Table to define valid states and event of finite state machine
static afEventHandler StateMachine =
{
    [Idle_State] ={[Card_Insert_Event]= InsertCardHandler },
    [Card_Inserted_State] ={[Pin_Enter_Event] = EnterPinHandler },
    [Pin_Eentered_State] ={[Option_Selection_Event] = OptionSelectionHandler},
    [Option_Selected_State] ={[Amount_Enter_Event] = EnterAmountHandler},
    [Amount_Entered_State] ={[Amount_Dispatch_Event] = AmountDispatchHandler},
};
```

Then an array of the type described above is declared and initialized using designated initializers.

Here is a much more simplified example of a similar typedef declaration of a one-dimensional array of function pointers using an enumeration.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum { Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide, TotalOperations } Operation;

typedef int ( * const Action[TotalOperations] )( int, int );

int add( int x, int y )      { return x + y; }
int subtract( int x, int y ) { return x - y; }
int multiply( int x, int y ) { return x * y; }
int divide( int x, int y )   { return x / y; }

int main(void) 
{
    Action action =
    {
        [Add] = add, [Subtract] = subtract, [Multiply] = multiply, [Divide] = divide
    };
    
    int x = 100, y = 5;
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < TotalOperations; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", action[i]( x, y ) );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
105
95
500
20
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clear breakdown of terms. My biggest confusion was actually on the declaration of ```StateMachine```. I did not know about designated initializers and everything looked so bulky.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef eSystemState (*const afEventHandler[last_State][last_Event])(void);
```

defines `afEventHandler` as a 2D array of function pointers that have no parameter and returns an `eSystemState`.

```
 static afEventHandler StateMachine =
    {
        [Idle_State] ={[Card_Insert_Event]= InsertCardHandler },
        [Card_Inserted_State] ={[Pin_Enter_Event] = EnterPinHandler },
        [Pin_Eentered_State] ={[Option_Selection_Event] = OptionSelectionHandler},
        [Option_Selected_State] ={[Amount_Enter_Event] = EnterAmountHandler},
        [Amount_Entered_State] ={[Amount_Dispatch_Event] = AmountDispatchHandler},
    };
```

is the initialisation of a variable `StateMachine` of the defined type.

```
 StateMachine[IdleState]
```

is then initialised as an 1D array of pointers to function no parameter, returning `eSystemState` with:

```
{[Card_Insert_Event]= InsertCardHandler }
```

an 1D array whose element of index `Card_Insert_Event` correspond to the function `InsertCardHandler`.